# Loopback adapter name in Linux

Tags: linux, networking, network-programming

Is it safe to assume that the loopback network adapter on a Linux system will always be called 'lo' - is this just a naming convention that may not be adhered to, or must it always be the case?

Comment: It is a naming convention followed by most linux distros. Some call it lo0, notably MacOS.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know of any Linux system that has a loopback interface anything other than `lo`. I would rely on this naming convention, if I write a system-specific script, but not when writing a portable program. For example loopback in OSX is `lo0`.

A reliable way in C is calling a `SIOCGIFCONF` `ioctl` on a socket, iterating over the interfaces, calling `SIOCGIFFLAGS` `ioctl` on each one, and checking which interfaces have a `IFF_LOOPBACK` flag set (see `/usr/include/linux/if.h`).

`SIOCGIFCONF` will also give you interface names.

Comment: This appears to have the advantage of not requiring any IPv4 ("127.0.0.1") address to be configured on the system.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience it is a common name, although you shouldn't always trust in it being so.  Maybe enumerating the interfaces and looking for the one with an address of 127.0.0.1 would be the way to go?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is one of several possible loopback addresses. It's a common error to assume that's the only one. Any address that looks like 127.x.x.x is a loopback address as well.

Answer (score 1):

It's a pretty old convention, in fact I have not seen a Linux box/distro yet that didn't call it 'lo'.

However, device names in *nix systems are so diverse it can be assumed they will change. Use the standards if you want portability (in this case, 127.0.0.1).

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces can be renamed to anything you want - but anyone who renames the loopback interface is being extremely silly and deserves to have a nonworking system :)

Yes, you can enumerate the interfaces, and get their names. But perhaps it's just as easy to just assume it's going to be "lo".

Answer (score -1):

Using 127.0.0.1 is probably the failsafe way to go about it.

Answer (score -2):

[RFC3330](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3330) defines `127.0.0.0/8` to always be the loopback subnet.

The use of `localhost` however, defined on Windows in `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` and Linux in `/etc/hosts` is purely convention. Furthermore the name `lo` is the typical name given to the localhost **interface** in Linux.

If you must be absolutely certain, use `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: RFC3330 defines 127.0.0.0/8 as the subnet for loopback addresses. All it says about 127.0.0.1 is that it is ordinarily used as the loopback address. You could be using 127.0.1.1 as a loopback address if you want. -1 for not reading the RFC you linked to and then giving wrong advice.

Comment: lo is not the same as 127.0.0.1. This would be ipv4 only. Worse yet, this wouldn't cover all the other loopback addresses -- 127.0.0.2 through 127.255.255.255, all of which also are loopback addresses.